# Applying multiple filters on a form/report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking to be able to allow users to apply multiple filters on a form/report. Let me explain further.
I have a subform (embedded in a form) which is already filtered by an option box which I have created. I would like to add ANOTHER Option box.. Is it possible.
To simplify my requirement let me explain further.  In my sub form you can filter by the status of my records (i.e. Open, closed, pending, ect)..   I would like to add another option box which inlcuded the priority of the records (low, med, high, ect)..
I think my explanation is clear enough.
Any advice on how to go about doing so would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
A

Answer (score 3):

This is just a single filter that you would make in VBA using concatenation. My standard code would look something like this. Note that I've added a filter for the Description field, which you didn't mention having, just so you can see how to filter using LIKE *something*, which is sometimes referred to as a fuzzy search. You can just remove that code if you don't need it.

```
Private Sub cboStatus_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub cboPriority_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub

Private Sub cboDescription_AfterUpdate()
    Call FilterSubform
End Sub


Private Sub FilterSubform() 
    Dim strWhere as String

    'Make string
    If Nz(Me.cboStatus, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[Status] = '" & Me.cboStatus & "' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.cboPriority, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[Priority] = '" & Me.cboPriority & "' AND "
    End If

    If Nz(Me.cboDescription, "") <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "[Description] LIKE '*" & Replace(Me.cboDescription, "'", "''") & "*' AND "
    End If

    'Apply filter
    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strWhere = Left(strWhere, Len(strWhere)-5) 'Remove the extra AND
        Me.subForm.Form.Filter = strWhere
        Me.subForm.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.subForm.Form.Filter = ""
        Me.subForm.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you HK1..   Excuse me but I am new to this and its possible i am not using the right terminology..   IN my question I was referring to two "option boxes" where you have the different circles to choose from..   My plan was to have two sets of them (as explained in my question)..  Your code to me appears to be combo boxes.  Are you saying the logic is th esame..  Also if so, would you mind explaining to me the two combo boxes you listed, what the contents of each are??? Thanks, A

Answer (score 0):

If your record source is a query then you can  set the criteria for field(s) in the query to the controls in the form or subform. Then after a selection is made you can requery using the "After Update" event.

```
Me.Requery
```

By doing this you could have your records filtered by as many choices as you would like.